# Finding Factors of a Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, factoring

Consider the determinant with elements:

$a_{11} = ax-by-cz, a_{12}=ay+cz, a_{13}=cx+az$
$a_{21}=ay+bx, a_{22}=by-cz-ax, a_{23}=bz+cy$
$a_{31}=cx+az, a_{32}=bz+cy, a_{33}=cz-ax-by$

Where $a_{ij}$ represents the element in the $i^{th}$ row and $j^{th}$ column.

I started out with 2 empty $3X3$ determinants to factorize this. The first row of the second determinant was filled as $a(1,1)=x, a(1,2)=y, a(1,3)=z$ and first row of the first determinant was filled as $a(1,1)=a,a(2,1)=b,a(3,1)=c$. 
I am not finding a good continuation to find the solution to the problem. Also, how do I improve my matrix/determinant factorizing skills? It takes me quite a while to fill in 2 empty determinants to get the original one as the product. Especially when it comes to problems like these where factor theorem cannot be easily applied. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Is $a_{11}=ax-by+cz$, rather than $ax-by-cz$? It seems curiously unsymmetrical.

Comment: i apologize. yes, it is $-cz$